# How select specific tenant after enter on console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multi-tenant, apartment-gem

The code below, stored at `config/initializers/console.rb` works only at first time I exec `rails console` CLI. When exit and enter again, no selection message is displayed, but the preview tenant selected is loaded.

```
if defined?(Rails::Console) || $PROGRAM_NAME.include?('spring')
  tenants = Apartment.tenant_names.sort
  default = tenants.first

  puts "Available tenants: #{tenants.join(', ')}"

  print "Select tenant (#{default}): "
  tenant = gets.strip

  Apartment::Tenant.switch! tenants.include?(tenant) ? tenant : default
end
```

I wish every time when enter at `rails console` ask for what tenant will be loaded.

Thanks!

Comment: It's works in my case. Rails version?

Comment: Your proposed solution worked for me once I removed gem `spring` from my project. The Rails maintainers excluded `spring` from rails 7 as the speed benefits are negligible for modern computers: https://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2021/9/15/Rails-7-0-alpha-1-released/#a-few-other-highlights

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way I could get Apartment::Tenant.switch! to work in the Rails console was by creating the following .irbrc file in the project's root directory:

```
IRB.conf[:IRB_RC] = Proc.new do
  tenants = Apartment.tenant_names.sort
  puts "Available tenants: #{tenants.join(', ')}"

  print "Select tenant: "
  tenant = gets.strip

  unless tenant.empty?
    if tenants.include?(tenant)
      Apartment::Tenant.switch!(tenant)
    else
      puts "Tenant not found in list '#{tenant}'"
    end
  end
  puts "Tenant set to '#{Apartment::Tenant.current}'"
end
```

Comment: Check this for `pry` version https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53251640/apartmenttenant-switch-during-bin-rails-console-using-pry

Answer (score 4):

I faced similar issue. If you are using the Apartment Gem. In your rails console you can switch between tenants by first connecting to DB and then using `schema_search_path`

```
e.g.
c = Company.connection
c.schema_search_path = "tenant1"
```

To check tenant has been switched use `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.schema_search_path`

> => "\"tenant1\""

Company is just a table in my DB.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple code (`pry` version) usable at `launch` or while at `console`

[`Apartment::Tenant.switch!` during `bin/rails console` using `pry`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53251640/apartmenttenant-switch-during-bin-rails-console-using-pry)

Answer (score 0):

This happens because of Spring, by default it's configured only for the development environment. Just remove it from your Gemfile and it should work as you expected.